# Asus Laptop charging inconsistently

Tags: laptop, battery

I own a Asus laptop that runs on Windows 10 and I'm having trouble properly charging it. 
The Laptop will only charge if I put pressure on it with a finger in a certain angle. If I remove the pressure or push it towards a different direction, the charger will not be detected by the laptop and my battery will drain. I have owned the laptop for roughly half a year and I'm not sure if I need a new charger or to get repairs done on my computer. It has been doing this for about a month now with no noticeable evidence that points towards the source of the problem. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely some part of the wire has been tugged and has a bad connection. Sounds like it’s by the DC jack itself. When you press the jack, you close the connection, enabling the current to flow. The port will rarely fail, since it’s embedded and sturdy.

You can fix the cable if you really want to, just order the right DC jack (google the laptop), solder it to the cable, and add bits of heatshrink tubing. I guess doing this sucks.

Before getting a replacement charger, try cleaning both jack and port with isopropyl alcohol. If it doesn’t help, you’ll need a new charger. A universal charger with multiple types of DC jack is going to be cheaper than an official ASUS charger.

You don’t write which ASUS laptop you own. It doesn’t matter much either - the power brick will have a label that tells you what voltage the laptop needs. Last ASUS laptop I used was an ultrabook, charged with 19V.